# How do I add custom module distributions to my local CPAN mirror?

Tags: perl, cpan, dpan

I'm getting ready to set up a full CPAN mirror for internal use at my company.  However, we have several internal `Module::Build` based distributions that I'd like to make available to people from this mirror.  These distributions should ONLY be available from our mirror; they are internal libraries only.  Essentially, once people have set up their CPAN config file to load  "cpan.mycompany.com' mirror, I'd like them to be able to do a

```
cpan install MyCompany::Bundle
cpan install MyCompany::Other::Module
```

On their command line to install any number of internal, custom module distributions.  Ideally, as versions of these module distributions are incremented, all of those versions would be indexed by our internal CPAN mirror and made available, just as as previous versions of CPAN modules are made available.

After the initial question, I was able to come up with some other possibilities.

There's [CPAN::Inject](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?CPAN%3a%3aInject), but it looks like I can't use it to get a  `cpan install My::Module` syntax.

Then there's [MyCPAN::App::DPAN](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?MyCPAN%3a%3aApp%3a%3aDPAN), which also looks interesting, and almost looks like what I need.  Does anyone have experience with this tool?

Another one I just came across was [CPAN::Site](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?CPAN%3a%3aSite).  This seems to also be able to set up a custom CPAN distribution.  Any thoughts on this tool?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this with a full CPAN mirror, [CPAN::Site](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?CPAN%3a%3aSite) covers this nicely.  It lets you make a mirror, and then inject your own libraries right into it, complete with tools to help you manage setting it up and keeping it up to date.

Answer (score 5):

If you're using [CPAN::Mini](http://search.cpan.org/dist/CPAN-Mini/) to create your mirror, then you use [CPAN::Mini::Inject](http://search.cpan.org/dist/CPAN-Mini-Inject/) to add your own modules to it.

Comment: I intend to have a full CPAN mirror.  This is for an enterprise, so space is not a concern, and previous versions are important.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to second the suggestion for [CPAN::Site](http://search.cpan.org/dist/CPAN-Site/) - the author is responsive and will gladly apply fixes if you ask or file a bug report on the [CPAN RT](https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Dist/Display.html?Name=CPAN-Site).

I've been using it recently to make a "micro-cpan" containing only what a particular application needs and nothing else, along with [cpanminus](http://search.cpan.org/dist/App-cpanminus/) to make installation in any environment dead-simple. However, don't ask me for my solution - [miyagawa](https://github.com/miyagawa)++ was at [YAPC::NA](http://www.yapc2011.us/) this year and showed off "[Carton](http://search.cpan.org/dist/carton/)" which does all that and more, *way* better than my hacky stuff.

[CPAN::Mini::Inject](http://search.cpan.org/dist/CPAN-Mini-Inject/) is perhaps a bit too "low-level" in that it requires that you specify a whole lot of information about each dist up-front before injecting into the minicpan - I feel that just about all of that should be auto-detected by analyzing the dist, for example by using [CPAN::ParseDistribution](http://search.cpan.org/dist/CPAN-ParseDistribution/).

[MyCPAN::App::DPAN](http://search.cpan.org/dist/MyCPAN-App-DPAN/) is actually quite cool, but has a bit of a learning curve and may not be the right tool for the job. I've also found it has a tendency to choke on some badly-formed dists and detecting that involves treawling through the logs (as far as I can tell - maybe there's a better way to do it) However, I'd highly suggest checking it out.

Answer (score 0):

If you're still interested in MyCPAN::App::DPAN, I've just posted how I use it to create a mini CPAN-like directory structure, in (one of) the answers to this question:

[Internal CPAN - what module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6648865/internal-cpan-what-module)

(I don't know if it's OK to link to my own answer here. Let me know if it isn't.)